# Vectorizing or speed up for loop in Pandas for data transformation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Parent_username': ['Bob1', 'Ron23', 'Lisa00', 'Joe_'],
                   'Parent_age': [38, None, 40, 26],
                   'Child1_name': ['Mike', 'John', 'Curt', 'Kelly'],
                   'Child1_age': [2, None, 1, 2],
                   'Child2_name': ['Pat', 'Dennis', None, None],
                   'Child2_age': [4, None, None, None]}) 

  Parent_username  Parent_age Child1_name  Child1_age Child2_name  Child2_age
0            Bob1        38.0        Mike         2.0         Pat         4.0
1           Ron23         NaN        John         NaN      Dennis         NaN
2          Lisa00        40.0        Curt         1.0        None         NaN
3            Joe_        26.0       Kelly         2.0        None         NaN
```

As you can see above, each row corresponds to a parent (unique ID), and each parents can have multiple children. There can be many children but I have 2 listed, and each child can have many attributes, but I only have 2 (name, age) in this example. The child attribute columns follow the same convention.

I'd like to transform it to such:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Child_name': ['Mike', 'Pat', 'John', 'Dennis', 'Curt', 'Kelly'],
                    'Child_number': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1],
                    'Child_age': [2, 4, None, None, 1, 2],
                    'Parent_username': ['Bob1', 'Bob1', 'Ron23', 'Ron23', 'Lisa00', 'Joe_'],
                    'Parent_age': [38, 38, None, None, 40, 26]})

  Child_name  Child_number  Child_age Parent_username  Parent_age
0       Mike             1        2.0            Bob1        38.0
1        Pat             2        4.0            Bob1        38.0
2       John             1        NaN           Ron23         NaN
3     Dennis             2        NaN           Ron23         NaN
4       Curt             1        1.0          Lisa00        40.0
5      Kelly             1        2.0            Joe_        26.0
```

Each row corresponds to a child, and the Child_number indicates if it's the first child or second child, etc.

In order to speed things up, I pre-allocated space for df2 by making an empty dataframe of the right size, rather than doing concatenation. I first looped through df1 by counting how many children each parent has, to get the number of rows needed for df2.

Then, I built dictionaries of indexes to map each child/parent to its row/rows in df2. I figure since dictionary lookup is fast, this is better than trying to find the row in df2 each time using where(). Again, a for loop was used for this.

Those actually does not take long. But the actual copying of the data from df to df2 takes a long time using for loop:

```
for index in df.index:
    for col in df.columns:
        // copy df.loc[index, col] into the corresponding position in df2 using dataframe.loc
```

I'm really hoping there is a faster way to do this. I don't understand vectorization very well and I'm not sure if it works well for string columns.

Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: I would start by restructuring your input data so that the DataFrame has columns ['Id', 'Name', 'Parent', 'Age', ..other Attributes ].  The 'Parent' column would then contain either a NaN if the Row is a 1s Generation Parent or an ID pointing to the ID of the Parent.

Comment: Why do you think concatenation is slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is slow because you are working on each element one at a time. You can speed it up by working on a column at a time. The code below finds all child name columns, finds the indexes where they have a value (i.e. not null) and operates on all those fields at once.

I also added ways to list all the attributes ahead of time so that you don't have to manually rename them individually.

```
cnames =  [i for i in df.columns if i.startswith('Child') and i.endswith('name')]
cattrs = ['_name', '_age']
newnames = ['Child' + i for i in cattrs]
dflist = []


for childcol in cnames:
    cid = childcol.split('_')[0]
    cnum = int(cid[-1])
    attrs  = [cid + i for i in cattrs] # get all the attributes
    attrs.extend(['Parent_username', 'Parent_age'])
    
    cdf = df.loc[df[childcol].dropna().index, attrs]
    cdf['Child_number'] = cnum
    
    cdf = cdf.rename(columns=dict(zip(attrs, newnames)))
    dflist.append(cdf)
    
newdf = pd.concat(dflist)
newdf = newdf.reset_index(drop=True)
```